# Strange Error 400 while using HttpRequest to consume REST API

Tags: c#, visual-studio, rest, httpwebrequest, http-status-code-400

I am trying to consume a REST API and i have an issue that it is driving me crazy...

I created a dll to wrap the service consumption layer, and i found that if i consume the services using the c# interactive feature it works fine.

The issue is when i try to consume it from another DLL, it is throwing Bad Request exception when executing GetResponse()

The code executed is...

```
var url = $"{_salesForceInstance}/services/data/{_salesForceVersion}/query/?q=SELECT+Id,Name,AccountId+from+Contact+WHERE+Email+=+'{email}'";
            var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            webRequest.ServicePoint.CloseConnectionGroup(webRequest.ConnectionGroupName);
            webRequest.Method = "GET";
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {_authorizationToken}");
            var webResponse =  webRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

I also when debugging code, to send the same through POSTMAN and it works fine...

Any ideas??? I am quite frustrated at this point why it works when consuming the dll from C# interactive but not from another dll...

Comment: So, open a copy of [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and make sure that the requests really do match. They almost certainly don't.

Comment: Thanks ! That helped !

Comment: I tried with Wireshark.. but i didint find anything... it seems that the issue is related to TLS version

Answer (score 1):

As spender suggested i tried with Fiddler...

I found that despite of the fact both request looks the same, (the one from c# interactive and the one from the console app), in the one that returned the HTTP 400 error code the response included the following message

"[{"message":"TLS 1.0 has been disabled in this organization. Please use TLS 1.1 or higher when connecting to Salesforce using https.","errorCode":"UNSUPPORTED_CLIENT"}]"

That message does not appear when debugging...

Finally i solved by including the line described below in my code in order to use TLS 1.2

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Now it works !!!

Hope this helps to someone else!

Thanks!